# How do I prevent my wordpress multisite redirecting to the home page including a trailing slash?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, multisite

I have created a Wordpress multisite but when I go one of the multisites it automatically adds a trailing slash to the homepage URL. My multisite is also in a subdirectory, I am not sure if this is affecting it. So for example:

`www.example.com/core/resource/site1`

redirects to:

`www.example.com/core/resource/site1/`

I have tried updating the database and amending the URLs so that they do not include a trailing slash however when I do this the site breaks. It still trys to redirect and I get a "Error establishing a database connection" page. As expected.

This is what I currently have in my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com/error.log error;

    root /data/wordpress/mysite;

    index  index.html index.php;

    rewrite ^/$ /wp/index.php break;

#   Rewrite multisite '.../wp-.*' and '.../*.php'.

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(wp-admin/.*)$ /wp/$1 last;
        rewrite ^/core/resource(/[^/]+)?(/wp-admin/.*)$ /core/resource/wp/$2 last;

        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/core/resource(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) /core/resource/wp$2 last;
        rewrite ^/core/resource(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php)$ /core/resource/wp$2 last;
    }

    location /core/resource {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /core/resource/wp/index.php?$args;
    }

    rewrite ^/(wp-includes/.*)$ /core/resource/wp/$2 last;

    include global/media.conf;
    include global/php.conf;
    include global/wordpress-w3tc.conf;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Can anyone advise how I prevent the wordpress multisite auto trailing slash? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by adding `remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');` to my functions.php file. I also had to clear cache in my browser.